# Access Tomcat from iPad

Tags: ipad, tomcat

I have installed Tomcat 7 on my Macbook. The IP address of Tomcat is : 127 . 0 . 0. 1

I would like to access it from my iPad. I don't know how to do that. I ve tried this address http:// 127. 0. 0. 1:8080 from my iPad but it doesn't work.

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean iPad simulator or real iPad device on some WiFi network ?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the ip of the current computers loop-back adapter (virtual network interface; so your device can address itself in the network, without a lookup). You need to find out your MacBooks real/ipv4 ip address. Try one of these:

1. System Preferences -> Network
2. Open a terminal -> type: ifconfig |grep inet

Comment: right, I wasn't pointing at the right ip address. Thank you for your help!